# "require.resolve is not a function" in babel-node eval mode

Tags: javascript, node.js, vim, babeljs

I'm trying to write a Vim command to follow a require/import reference (respecting module-resolver aliases) in js/ES6 files.

If I type `babel-node` and drop into REPL mode, I can do something like:

```
> require.resolve('~');
/properly/resolved/path
```

However, if I try to eval the same expression (I need to eval to specify the path from Vim during runtime) I get:

```
$ babel-node -e 'console.log(require.resolve("~"))'
[eval]:1
console.log(require.resolve("./lib/webapp/lib"));
                    ^

TypeError: require.resolve is not a function
    at [eval]:1:-41
    at ContextifyScript.Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:23:33)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:95:38)
    at _eval (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/lib/_babel-node.js:99:23)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/lib/_babel-node.js:119:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
```

It looks like the tilde is properly resolved (`~` points to `./lib/webapp/lib`) but is then inserted into the command, and babel tries to execute the function after it (not finding it for some reason).

Am I doing something wrong here? Is this a bug?

Comment: I'm not sure where Vim is involved in this issue.

Comment: Removed the tag.

Comment: Adding the Vim tag back since the workaround is pure Vim

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this problem with a temporary file and some rather nasty vimscript:

```
" Follow JavaScript references with proper babel (and module-resolver)
" resolution (required a git repo in the project's root)
function FollowJsReference()
  " Find the reference and yank it into the r register
  exec "normal ^f'\"ryi'"
  " Create a file at the root with the code for babel-node to resolve the
  " reference. Ideally, I'd do this with babel-node's eval, but it errors out.
  " Instead, I create a script, evaluate it then delete it.
  let s:script_content = 'console.log(require.resolve("' . @r . '"));'
  let s:create_command = 'tee `git rev-parse --show-toplevel`/___resolve.js'
  call system(s:create_command, s:script_content)
  " Run babel-node from the root dir
  let s:babel_command = 'cd `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` && babel-node ./___resolve.js'
  let s:out = system(s:babel_command)
  exec ":edit " . s:out
  " Clean up
  let s:delete_command = 'rm `git rev-parse --show-toplevel`/___resolve.js'
  call system(s:delete_command)
endfunction
nnoremap <Leader>gj :call FollowJsReference()<CR>
```